# Passing structures in pthread

Tags: c, parallel-processing, pthreads

I am trying to pass a structure when creating a thread but does not seem to work correctly!

Here is the structure:

```
struct analyse_data {
    int verbose; //should be 1 or 0
};
```

Note that verbose can only be 1 or 0 and nothing else.

Here is the method being called (note it can be called multiple times by another method):

```
void dispatch(struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const unsigned char *packet,
        int verbose) {

    static bool thread_settings_initialised = false;

    printf("Verbose: %d\n", verbose); //Prints 1 or 0

    //Only run the first time dispatch method runs
    if (thread_settings_initialised == false){
        thread_settings_initialised = true;

        //...    

        //Set mutex for the appropriate variables to remain thread safe
        //...

        //Set attr so threads are "Detached"
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

        //Set pthread_cond_init
        //...
    }

    //Put parameters into a struct so can be sent in a thread
    struct analyse_data data;
    data.verbose = verbose;

    //...

    pthread_t tid;
    printf("data.verbose: %d\n", data.verbose); //This prints 1 or 0
    int rc = pthread_create( &tid, &attr, bar, (void *) &data);
    if (rc) {
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
    }

}
```

and this is the method thats being called by the thread:

```
void analyse(void *thread_data) {
    struct analyse_data *data;
    data = (struct analyse_data *) thread_data;
    int verbose = data->verbose;
    printf("Verbose =  %d\n", verbose ); //Prints weird numbers like -547845...
}
```

As you can see from my comments, the value of verbose changes when being used inside the method. Why? What am I doing Wrong?

Many Thanks!

**Update (thanks to JS1)**
I updated my code to use a pointer:

```
void dispatch(struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const unsigned char *packet,
        int verbose) {

    static bool thread_settings_initialised = false;

    printf("Verbose: %d\n", verbose); //Prints 1 or 0

    //...

    //Put parameters into a struct so can be sent in a thread
    struct analyse_data *data = malloc(sizeof(struct analyse_data)); //NEW
    data->verbose = verbose;

    //...

    pthread_t tid;
    printf("data.verbose: %d\n", data.verbose); //This prints 1 or 0
    int rc = pthread_create( &tid, &attr, bar, (void *) data);
    //...
}
```

But now the analyse() method always outputs 0, even when verbose is 1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not pass a stack variable to `pthread_create`.  Notice that `data` is local to the function `dispatch` and will be out of scope when `dispatch` returns.  You should instead either use `malloc` to allocate `data`, or use a static or global variable.

If you use the `malloc` method, it will look like this:

```
struct analyse_data *data = malloc(sizeof(struct analyse_data));
data->verbose = verbose;

int rc = pthread_create( &tid, &attr, bar, data);
```

You must remember to not call `free` on `data` from `dispatch`.  The memory should "belong" to the thread, so you should eventually call `free` on `data` from the thread when you are done using the contents of `data`.

Comment: so is this correct:
struct analyse_data *data = malloc(sizeof(struct analyse_data));
data->verbose = verbose;
...
int rc = pthread_create( &tid, &attr, analyse, (void *) data);

Comment: It works better, but not quite right. On the first subroutine (dispatch) it prints out 1 as expected but on the 2nd it prints out 0 always! I'll update my question to reflect problem

Comment: Are you saying that it prints 0 from `dispatch()` or `analyse()`?

Comment: You didn't call `free` on data, did you?

Comment: That worked! Thanks. Why did I have to call free anyway. (surely that just frees up memory and not replace existing memory assuming you don't use too much). Also should I have free in the analyse or the dispatch or both? I put it in analyse.

Comment: also is the (void *) part still required now?